# OracleConnection does not support parallel transactions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, oracle11g, enterprise-library

I'm working with Oracle 11g database and ASP.NET MVC 4 using Enterprise library. I use Transactions on my commands just to be safe if case of any exceptions. I've a main method with BeginTransaction() which calls other methods (Lets call it child method) that contain Begin and Commit Transaction methods.
I'm getting "OracleConnection does not support parallel transactions." exception when I am executing BeginTransaction() method in child method.

Any help on this.

Comment: Have you tried adding `enlist=false` into your connection string?

Comment: I tried it and that did not work. BTW, I'm connecting to oracle server through VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [TransactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152(v=vs.90).aspx) instead of BeginTransaction method. It supports distributed nested transactions therefore it should help.

```
void RootMethod()
{
     using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
     {
          /* Perform transactional work here */
          SomeMethod();
          scope.Complete();
     }
}

void SomeMethod()
{
     using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
     {
          /* Perform transactional work here */
          scope.Complete();
     }
}
```